# In cocos2dx v3. How can both scale and rotate with different center

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I use cocos2dx v3.5. I want scale and rotate sprite with different center.
I have tried by:

```
spriteCoin->setAnchorPoint(Point::ANCHOR_BOTTOM_LEFT);
spriteCoin->setRotation(30.0f);
spriteCoin->setAnchorPoint(Point::ANCHOR_MIDDLE);
spriteCoin->setScale(2.0f, 3.0f);
```

but it does not work

Comment: You can't do that expect with some trick. Try this: Create a `Node` and put your `spriteCoin` in this empty node. Now you can set two different `anchorPoint` for `Node` and `Sprite` and do your action separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to rotate or scale sprites, you need to change position as rotate or scale.